# Straight lines across slope raster

Tags: r, arcgis, terra

I am trying to create slope, aspect and TRI rasters from a DEM .tif file.

When I run the code:

library(terra)

library(raster)

DEM_movement <- raster("path_to_DEM_here.tif") #1 harddrive

slope<-terrain(DEM_movement, opt='slope', unit='degrees', neighbors=8)

I am able to generate a slope raster, but it has diagonal lines across the entire raster, as shown in the image below:
[slope raster showing diagonal lines running through image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeTyr.png)

The DEM doesn't have these lines:
[close up of DEM used to generate slope raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh3J7.png)

Does anyone know what is causing this?

The DEM that I used for this can be downloaded here to reproduce my issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qttt6g9iuelripn/DEM_clipped_to_movement2.tif?dl=0

I have tried to generate a slope raster in ArcGIS Pro as well, as had the same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.